# Generic Types in Java and Hash Codes

Tags: java, generics, hashcode

Although I know this is not the most efficient way to creating a hash code, I am working to make hash codes by converting data to integers and this will be their hash codes. I am approaching this with data types that are only 32 bits or less(thus just byte,integer,character,short and float). While creating a program I have run across a problem that has to due with generics. I have a class that accepts only the data types that I talked about above by using the instanceof keyword in java within an if as such:

```
public class HashCode<T>
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        codeAsInt(2);
        codeAsInt('C');
        codeAsInt("name");
    }
    public int codeAsInt(T value)
    {
        if(value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Character || value instanceof Short || value instanceof Float || value instanceof Byte)
        {
        int hashcode = (int)value;
        return hashcode;
        }

        else
        {
            //you cannot use this method return -1
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

Doing this cause an error as I cannot convert "value" of any of these types to T. Is there anyway I can pass different data types to a method using generics? I know I could solve this problem using method overloading(creating different methods that accept different data types) but from what I have learnt method overloading is used with methods that do different things, for my method it does the same thing(converts data to ints). I also know I could have created a separate class to do this but I think this would be inefficient for such a simple task.

Error at compiling time:

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T
        codeAsInt(2);
                  ^
  where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Object declared in class HashCodes
 error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to T
        codeAsInt('C');
                  ^
  where T is a type-variable:
   T extends Object declared in class HashCodes
 error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to T
        codeAsInt("name");
                  ^
  where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Object declared in class HashCodes
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
3 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Any help would be appreciated as well as any approach that would be better then the approach I am using.

Comment: Actually, this looks like exactly what overloading is for. Use overloading.

Comment: This code wouldn't compile, because you're calling an instance method from a static context. Post the real code you're trying to execute, and the complete and exact error message. That said, the easiest way to get a hashCode for any type of object is to call `object.hashCode()`.

Comment: @JB Nizet The exact error that comes from this falls under what I am passing to the method. That is the following:

Comment: codeAsInt(2);
codeAsInt('C');
codeAsInt("name");

Comment: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T
  codeAsInt(2);
            ^

Comment: Don't post that in comments. Edit your question. Replace the fake code you posted by the real one. And post the exact and complete error message there.

Comment: Your method is not a static method so you cannot call it from `main()`. Meanwhile, you don't have an instance of the object on which to call the method so its pretty difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Why can't you just override `hashCode()`?

Comment: @JB Nizet I have updated my question with compiling error as well as extra code snippets.

Comment: @susyphus I am using the instanceof keyword for the 2, C and name objects passed to the method. That is an Integer a Character and a String. I could override the hashCode() but I am trying to apply the different ways to create hashcodes explicitly explained in one of the books I am reading. This is a simple way of creating hashcodes by casting 32 bit or less data types into integers. I have edited my question to reflect what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your posted code still produces different errors from what you are posting. Post the REAL code. But anyway: to call an instance method of a class, you need to create an object. That's something you should understand before even thinking about generics. So, to call codeAsInt(), you need something like `HashCode<Integer> h = new HashCode<>(); h.codeAsInt(2);`. I still don't understand the point of this class though. Just call hashCode() on any object, and you'll have its hashCode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The error message

The error you got comes from calling a generic non static method from a static context, i guess. To make your code compile, but not directly work ;), you should change your calls in the `main` method to something like this:

```
new HashCode<Integer>().codeAsInt(2);
new HashCode<Character>().codeAsInt('C');
new HashCode<String>().codeAsInt("name");
```

So in your case it is required to instantiate the class and specifiy the type of `T` when creating the object. It seems you want to let the compiler infer the type by the arguments.
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) Oracle gives hints about java's type inference mechanics, which would you allow to use your class as follows.

```
HashCode<Integer> i = new HashCode<>().codeAsInt(2);
HashCode<Character> c = new HashCode<>().codeAsInt('C');
HashCode<String> s = new HashCode<>().codeAsInt("name");

i.codeAsInt(2);
c.codeAsInt('C');
s.codeAsInt("name");
```

Thus you could leave out the type information on the instantiation, but not on the declaration. I am not 100% sure if it is possible with java 1.8's type inference to write this in an even cleaner way.

### A possible solution

Since java 1.7 and earlier it is possible to use java's type literals to achieve something similar. But then you'll have to pas that literal explicitly always to the method. Your whole class doesn't explicitly requires to be generic, if you want to select the type on every individual method call, it is sufficient to make a single method generic instead.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static <T> int codeAsInt(Class<T> type, T value) {
        // here you can use the type object
        if(type.isInstance(value)) {
        // ...
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        codeAsInt(Integer.class, 2);
        codeAsInt(Character.class, 'C');
        codeAsInt(String.class, "name");
    }
}
```

The [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) type gives you an object for the type `T` at runtime, because that isn't usually available anymore after compilation. With the `type` object you can do casting to `T` at runtime. There is some [`cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method, which takes an `Object` and returns a `T`. Furthermore you can check with the [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method if an object is of type `T`. However choosing the described approach makes the type check obsolete, because the compiler will inform you if you accidentally pass something to the method which is not of type `T`.

I am still not sure what you are exactly looking for, but I hope this helps. If you just want to cast an object of any type dynamically into a `T` just use the type literals cast method directly.

*Just written blindly, no warranties for typos or compile errors ;)*

Comment: I will try this, thank you! For the time being I will try anything that works as I would much rather continue my readings on hashcodes and hashtables instead of trying to find out why this damn code doesn't work lol. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I guess the problems arise from being new to generics in java, so if there are any follow up questions, leave a comment or modify your question accordingly, and we'll see ;)

Comment: It appears you're right. I've run across another problem that has to do with generics. I tried instead of using a class to implement the method talked about above. Thus that error of defining a generic method in a static context would not show up. I however have a new problem as when I pass a Byte to this method(for example) and try to cast it as an Integer an error arises as apparently you cannot cast Integers to Bytes(wrapper classes) however, you can convert int to  byte(primitive data types). Why is this and is there a work around to casting a Byte object into an Integer object?

Comment: With primitive types it is possible to cast around interchangeably, but when casting objects you have to take account class hierarchies. [``java.lang.Byte``](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) objects can be casted up and down the hierarchy. When type ``T`` can only be one of the primitive wrapper classes, then you can restrict your ``T`` to accept only subtypes of ``Number``. This way you could access the [``intValue``](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue). However, this may not work for ``Character``. Looks like an "XY problem"

Answer (score -2):

I think you're talking about [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)

Answer (score -2):

Here is a class using reflection, you'll have to deal with the throwed exception and manage them :

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) { // Manage command line argument

    try
    {
        System.out.println(getHashCode("java.lang.String", "10")); // For simplicity    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("There's a problem with this test ! Here is the details :\n"+e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static int getHashCode(String className, String value) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{

    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Constructor<?> c = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
    Object o = c.newInstance(value);
    return o.hashCode();
}
```

}